# Analyzing logs: how to get page views broken down by page?

Tags: wordpress, analytics, statistics, logging

I have a WordPress site where we didn't enable "pretty" permalinks, and thus, all pages in it have URLs in the form `?p=3921`. Now, when I log into the statistics page in my hosting provider, I see that the most visited page is `index.php`, which lumps together all the pages in the site, but I can't tell apart the visits for each page. I can download the raw access logs, though, so is there any web analyzer software that can show me access stats broken down by page?

(NOTE: this is not a request for WordPress plugins, or Google Analytics. Those might be useful in the future, once we've installed them, but the logs I'm trying to analyze now are from the last few weeks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your hosts built in web analytics software will break down page views for you, there won't be a great deal you can do if I follow correctly (and this will vary depending on host)..

Would it not be possible to import the raw access logs into MS Excel or similar and then use a program such as [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) to crawl your site. Export the list of URL's from your site and import into the same spreadsheet as your raw access log and then match the page query parameters (?p=3921) in URL against the relevant pages.

Unfortunately, 9 times out of 10, you need to be tracking visitor behaviour correctly before you can obtain any worthwhile data from any logs so Google Analytics is definitely recommended going forward (as the hosts web analytics software is useless).

Whilst you specifically state you don't want a plugin, I bet there is a Wordpress plugin out there that will be able to give you the data you want for the last two weeks.

## Extended Answer

You may wish to check out the likes of [WebLog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com/) or [Advanced Log Analyzer](http://www.abacre.com/ala/) and see if they have import options to import your raw log files. Aside from this, I really don't think there is anything else available that will do what you want.

Comment: No, my host's web analytics software doesn't break down page views correctly, but I can download the raw access logs, so what I'm asking is whether there is some "offline" web analytics package that I can feed my logs into and show me the goods. Any recommendations?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well, in the end WebLogExpert did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, you're welcome.